# C++: Storing user inputs

Tags: c++

I just want the user to enter some numbers. If the number is -1 the program stops and then outputs those same numbers. Why is that so difficult? I don't understand why the logic is not working here.

For example when the user types:

```
1 2 3 -1
```

The program should then print out:
    1
    2
    3
    -1

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int input, index=0;
    int array[200];

    do
    {
        cin >> input;
        array[index++]=input;
    } while(input>0);

    for(int i=0; i < index; i++)
    {
        cout << array[index] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? p.s. You should add an `return 0` at the end of the `main()`

Comment: What doesn't work the way you expect it?

Comment: When I type in 1 2 3 -1. I don't get those numbers back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this

```
for(int i=0; i < index; i++)
{
    cout << array[index] << endl;
}
```

To

```
for(int i=0; i < index; i++)
{
    cout << array[i] << endl;
}
```

You used `index` at the seconde loop causing your program to print all the array cell's **after** the user input.

Also, if `-1` is your condition you should change it to

```
} while(input>=0);
             ^^
```

Otherwise, also `0` will stop the loop, which is not what you asking for.

Comment: thanks I was getting really frustrated and then saw your comment. whew